# Another review audit failed

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

*Preamble*:
In the past I failed several audits and I accepted the 2 days break.

Because there is a suspension mechanism, now I skip all the reviews where I'm not 200% sure that is not a tricky test.

I just failed this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2418655

For me the answer was ok, what I missed this time?

Comment: It is a bit borderline, but the answer there is essentially a link-only answer. As a borderline example, it is not a good audit review post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I read the answer and also checked both links to be sure they are pertinent, agree with you that this a borderline example

Comment: Just got 2 downvotes, maybe this kind of questions are not permitted?

Comment: By deleting the actual post (most likely after getting some flags) the moderator signaled the system "this post is indeed bad, it can be used as audit". I can only advice to skip such answers as well, that contain only links without real explanation.

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: Is there any human contact before an audit is approved for use in the wild?

Comment: @RichardTingle No, I think there is none.

Comment: Is there any way to contact mods to consider lifting a review audit ban? I've failed several audits for nearly 1k done and now I've got an one month break. I'd really like to continue helping with SO reviews, but can't see any way to do it.